# How to use a list as index in dataframe.map()?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas df which looks like this:

```
ld_r2_array_df.head()
         SNP_A                  r2_ld_array
0  1:203337500  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
1   20:6730358  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
2   7:50878411  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
3  20:47025897  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
4   18:7553626  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
```

And a dict:

```
print(dict(list(csnps_indices.items())[0:2]))
{'10:100148542': [4582], '10:10091912': [4527]}
```

When I run the command below,

```
ld_r2_array_df["order"] = ld_r2_array_df.SNP_A.map(csnps_indices)
```

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4588, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._call_map_locations'
```

I am a complete python newbie, so I was wondering what might be the issue here. I already tried converting the dict to tuple, but then I received another error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Please let me know if I should provide further info for reproduction of the error. Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `csnps_indices`?

Comment: Stepping back, what are you hoping to do here?  Are you trying to use the string value there (`'10:100148542'`} to look up a row in the dataframe?

Comment: print(type(csnps_indices)): <class 'dict'>

Comment: I want to keep certain rows in my dataframe based on the indeces in the dict, then I will order them based on the order values.

Comment: Try to update your post with an input and an output that match please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me.

Input data:

```
>>> df
         SNP_A                  r2_ld_array
0  1:203337500  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
1   20:6730358  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
2   7:50878411  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
3  20:47025897  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]
4   18:7553626  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]

>>> d
{'1:203337500': [4582], '7:50878411': [4527]}
```

Try to map:

```
df['order'] = df['SNP_A'].map(d)
print(df)

# Output:
         SNP_A                  r2_ld_array   order
0  1:203337500  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]  [4582]
1   20:6730358  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]     NaN
2   7:50878411  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]  [4527]
3  20:47025897  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]     NaN
4   18:7553626  [1, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE]     NaN
```

Comment: I changed "ld_r2_array_df.SNP_A" notation to "df['SNP_A']", and indeed 'order' column is added to my df now. Is this some sort of a python version issue then? Weirdly I keep getting the same error message though, but this time my script keeps running somehow.

Comment: Ok it works with anaconda/3.2021.05, but not with anaconda/3.2019.10. Which python or conda version did you use?

Comment: @gokberk. Python = '3.9.7', Pandas = '1.3.3' and Numpy = '1.21.2'. For Anaconda/3.2019, you probably have a version of Pandas < 1.0.0 (maybe 0.25 or 0.24).